# What does "This is a systems or database administrator position" do?

Tags: support, jobs

When creating a job posting on careers, one of the options is:

- This is a systems or database administrator position

What exactly does this control? I know the little tooltip says "*By letting us know this is a systems or database administrator role, we can advertise in the right places in the network (such as ServerFault)*".
Does this mean it will not be advertised on StackOverflow?
Also what is "the right places"? Is it always ServerFault if that box is checked?

If my position I'm creating is a DevOps position, it blurs the line between admin and developer. I may not want to put it on one site if the option will remove it from the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The position will always be advertised on Stack Overflow. We simply allow a small percentage of impressions to appear on Server Fault (up to 10%) when you check that box.

And yes, it would only be Server Fault at the moment. There's no immediate plans to include other Stack Exchange sites.